# how can i Pass the Json Data from a local file to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

i have a json file with the below data mis.json

```
{
{"name": "lpcdpapp01.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
{"name": "lpcdpapp02.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
{"name": "lpcdpapp03.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
{"name": "lpcdpapp04.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"}
}
```

and I want to read this data in Javascript for search functionality . can some one help me how can i achieve this

```
   function form_submit() {
      var item = document.getElementById('ins').value;
      alert(item);
      var json = $.getJSON("mis.json", function(json) {
                    console.log(json); 
                });
      alert(json);
}
```

Please help here and also greatful for search algorithm to

Comment: In the alert dialog box it is showing nil and couldn't parse it

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. This means you will need to use the `json` variable within the callback *only*

Comment: what does your search algorithm need to do ?

Comment: You just need to write tour algo inside the ajax call. I mean $.getJSON("mis.json", function(json) {
                   //Your algo goes here
                });

Comment: `console.log(json);` near u can use `JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: @ManpreetSingh that will cause a syntax error as jQuery will already have deserialised the response text to an object. You'd be calling `parse` on an object.

Comment: @madalin search for any name in the JSON data abd display us the O/P

Comment: @Rory thanks for the response i will go through them